# How to exit the Vim editor when :q or :x doesn't work

Tags: exit, vi

Newbie to vi / vim, I normally use pico but using a locked down box (for now) that only has these 2 editors.

I am having trouble getting it to save a file or even just quit. I see others having the same issue and they were told to use :x but even that doesn't work, just throws up an error message.

Is there an exit command that JUST works?

thanks

Answer (score 10):

`:q` should work, unless the file hasn't been saved.

`:q!` will work.

`:wq` will attempt to save and quit, but won't quit if it can't save.

`:wq!` will attempt to save, and then quit whether or not it can save.

E: Credit to @GregoryNisbet for reminding me: if you have multiple files open, there is a series of 'all' quit commands:

`:qa` should quit all buffers (open files, more or less).

`:qa!` will quit all buffers regardless of if they have been saved.

`:wqa` will attempt to save and quit all buffers.

`:wqa!` will attempt to save all buffers, and then quit whether or not they are saved.

Comment: `:qa!` will quit an unlimited number of buffers regardless of their saved-ness

Comment: Don't forget to exit edit mode by pressing escape. For the truly new, it's possible to get stuck in edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that has worked for me is

1. Esp Z + Z
2. :wq!

Answer (score -2):

you should type :q not q.Every command in vim should start with :